# How do I update certain columns of an SQLAlchemy row without changing unspecified columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a table with 3 rows like this:

```
| serverID | behavior  | limit  |
---------------------------------
| 102      | action1   | 5      |
| 103      | action2   | 8      |
```

I have this function here:

```
def set_warn_settings(serverID, behavior, limit):
with INSERTION_LOCK:
    try:
        row = SESSION.query(WarnSettings).filter(WarnSettings.serverID == serverID).first()
        if row:
            row.behavior = behavior
            row.limit = limit

            SESSION.add(row)
            SESSION.commit()
        else:
            action = WarnSettings(serverID, behavior, limit)

            SESSION.add(action)
            SESSION.commit()
    finally:
        SESSION.close()
```

When I call the function and one of the arguments is `None`, the column's value is replaced with `None` instead of leaving it like was before. The function is sometimes called with only one of the arguments having something else than `None`.

How can I update a certain column's value while leaving the rest untouched, all from one function?

Comment: `row.behavior = behavior if behavior is not None else row.behavior`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it depends on what your requirements are...but you should check the value of `behavior` and `limit` before setting:

```
if behavior is not None:
    row.behavior = behavior
if limit is not None:
    row.limit = limit
```

However, you might consider that there will be times when you WANT to be able to set those fields to `None`. In that case you could set your parameters to a specific object by default. Example:

```
no_value = object()
def set_warn_settings(serverID, behavior=no_value, limit=no_value):

    ...
    if behavior is not no_value:
        row.behavior = behavior
    if limit is not no_value: 
        row.limit = limit
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could handle this would be to use the [`**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs#3394898) construct in your function signature. Then instead of using positional arguments when calling your function, call it with only the keyword arguments of the attributes that you wish to update:

```
def set_warn_settings(serverID, **kwargs):
    with INSERTION_LOCK:
        try:
            row = SESSION.query(WarnSettings).get(serverID)
            if row:
                for k, v in kwargs.items():
                    setattr(row, k, v)
                # i removed SESSION.add(row) from here as you don't need to 
                # re-add an instance that was retrieved via Session.query.
                SESSION.commit()
            else:
                action = WarnSettings(**kwargs)
                SESSION.add(action)
                SESSION.commit()
        finally:
            SESSION.close()
```

This will only update the values of the attribute names that you pass as keyword arguments to the function if the row exists, and will create a new `WarnSettings` instance with the passed in values if a row doesn't already exist. It will also not overwrite values of attributes that you don't want to have set to `None` but will also allow you to explicitly set a value to `None` if you need to.

Usage examples based on your example data:

```
set_warn_settings(102, behavior='action2')  # will change value of 'behavior' and not change 'limit'.
set_warn_settings(103, behavior='action1', limit=10)  # will change both fields
set_warn_settings(104, behavior='action3', limit=3)  # will create a new instance
```

Note I also used the [`.get()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get) method in the function which is a neat way to query by primary key and return `None` if a row doesn't exist.